# Find all the dependency higher versions available from pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I want to find all the higher versions available for each dependency and download them all of them. I tried to get the version by this command

```
versions:display-dependency-updates
```

But it is only displaying the latest version. Instead how should I find all higher versions using a java.

Comment: Btw, why do you need all versions? Do you want to download from public maven central repo? (Add more details )

Comment: I want to download all the versions from maven repo. All versions are required because i'm doing research on dependency upgrading for my university.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, updating all the dependencies of a project just for having the latest version isn't the most recommended option. You may encounter unintended consequences such as, for example, changing the Java version with which the projects were compiled so you can't deploy your application on your server. My recommendation is that you always keep control of the dependencies you use in your projects and define a specific value appropriate to your needs. But if the supplier of the dependencies is a trustworthy organization and maintains compatibility between its versions, you can use the maven dependency syntax to get the latest. [Dependency Version Ranges](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Dependency+Mediation+and+Conflict+Resolution#DependencyMediationandConflictResolution-DependencyVersionRanges)